# Performance and javascript issue in a drupal 7 website

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a drupal 7 website. Currently its performance is not good and takes much time to render the web pages. For performance, I checked out in YSlow and came up with some results like move all js files at bottom, compress them and images too etc.

As far as I know its drupal structure to render js first at the head and then it loads the body content. So, Is there any way to move all js files at bottom of the web page in drupal???

I tried to aggregate javascript and css files with the admin panel in drupal but that is breaking some features of the website, say for example, some jquery and ajax codes are not working. Please suggest something for these problems as how can I approach for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [advagg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg), but shoving [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) at the problem is usually easier, let them deal with the js complexity by converting it to rocketscript for you for free!

Or you could mention which modules you have, how many scripts you are attempting to load, whether they are asynchronous/deferred etc, what version of jQuery, perhaps even a link to the site itself so we can have a look?

Comment: Thanks for the comment... I can't give u the link this time as the website is password protected for now. jQuery version being used is 1.8.2, there are so many js files being used. Aggregation of js and css improved performance of the website. But some features getting break. So, I am unable to do that. Is it possible to move those js files at bottom with help of some modules or some hook_alter???

Comment: Did you try advagg? Its not normal aggregation, its a different module that does lots of tricks, including moving scripts into the footer if required.. have a look at the link provided.